# If one shortens prayer for travel during Ramadan, must they also not fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, travelling, salat-al-qasr

Someone travelling during Ramadan does not have to fast that day (but catch it up later); [Qur'an 2:184](https://quran.com/2/184).  Someone travelling can also shorten their prayer; [Qur'an 4:101](https://quran.com/4/101).

**Question**: If one shortens prayer for travel during Ramadan, must they also not fast?

It seems inconsistent to shorten the prayer due to travel, yet not break the fast due to travel.  But maybe I'm reading too much into this, and flexibility is intended.

---

To reiterate, this is the scenario:

1. We have someone who is travelling during Ramadan.
2. They don't have to fast that day due to travelling, but choose to fast anyway.
3. They shorten prayer that day due to travelling.

It seems inconsistent, and I'm wondering if this is not allowed.

Comment: One who is travelling a distance greater than 76 kms can refrain from fasting.  Make up those fast later

Comment: Your scenario is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I perceived about the question (correct me please, if I am wrong), the answer briefly can be so:

**The significant remarkable point (at least based on Shia-Islam's view, but I am not aware of Sunni-Islam's view) is as follows:
A traveler must not fast, and actually it is haram (forbidden) for a traveler to fast -in the trip-, and actually (AFAIK, based on Shia's perspective) this verse (i.e. above-mentioned verse) doesn't mean that it is optional for you as a traveler to fast or not, and in truth it mentions that a traveler must not fast.**

Conclusion:

Hence, a traveler shortens the prayer and doesn't fast, and these two are not optional but are as order, consequently there does't be consistent in that. Good luck.

---

Reference: [wiki.ahlolbait.com](http://wiki.ahlolbait.com) and [www.nasr19.ir](http://www.nasr19.ir/1391/05/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B9%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%B1-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%D9%89-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%9F%D8%9F%D8%9F/)